# Accessing current session in IBM Notes web-provider

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-notes

I have a java web-provider in IBM Notes. 
I try to access to  the  current NotesSession via AgentBase:

```
import lotus.domino.AgentBase;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.AgentContext;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.Document;

public class HwProvider extends AgentBase{ 
    public String createOrder (String subject, String fio){
        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
            Database database = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();

            return subject + " " + fio; 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I receive this error while testing in SOAP UI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <createOrderReturn xmlns="urn:DefaultNamespace">java.lang.NullPointerException</createOrderReturn>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I access to the  current session?

Answer (score 1):

Inside an WS Provider, there is no need to reference an `AgentBase`. You could rely on `Session s = WebServiceBase.getCurrentSession();` to get the current session.